# Auth headers getting removed when requesting absolute url

Tags: angularjs, restful-authentication

When I try to make a request to a local url everything works just fine. However when I change the url to the actual url of our test server (prefixed with http) the http auth header seems to be stripped from the request.
The commented $http... works. But the one below doesn't.
Anyone got a clue about why that happens?

```
function OneCitizensList($scope, $http) {
   var username = "user",
      password = "pass";

   $scope.citizen = [];
   $scope.medication = [];

// $http.get('/mobile/unity/patient/?patientId=36', {
   $http.get('http://something:8083/unity/medication/list?patientId=102', {
   headers: {
       'Authorization': "Basic " + Base64Encoder(username + ':' + password)
     }
     }).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         console.log(data);

      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         console.log("Error");
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a bracket in your headers object.

```
$http.get('http://something:8083/unity/medication/list?patientId=102', {
   headers: {
       {'Authorization': "Basic " + Base64Encoder(username + ':' + password)}
     }
     }).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         console.log(data);

      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         console.log("Error");
      });
```

Or the full method(not short-hand) :

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://something:8083/unity/medication/list?patientId=102', headers: {
    'Authorization': "Basic " + Base64Encoder(username + ':' + password)}
});
```

**Also make sure your server allows CORS requests.**

In order for basic auth to work, you also need `withCredentials: true`, in your $http config.

Example:

```
$http.get('https://yourURL.test', { headers: {your_headers}, withCredentials: true});
```

Comment: It doesn't work with the extra {}. And also, it works with a local url. It's just when I use a remote url seems like the auth header is stripped from the request as shown in the chrome dev console.